# Problem in Wrapping Figure

Tags: floats, wrapfigure

[image: I keep getting this text around wrapping figure and can't seem to solve it!]

---

I keep getting text like this around the wrap figure. I used the following piece of code:

---

[image]

Would appreciate so much if somebody could tell me what's going on! Thanks!!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Can you add your complete MWE, please?

Comment: please post the actual code so people can reproduce the problem, not just an image. However all the`\\ ` you show in the text at the bottom are wrong (and will produce underfull hbox badness 10000 warnings)

Comment: You shouldn't use `\begin{center}...\end{center}` in a `wrapfigure`. Additionally you don't need to use a bigger `wrapfigure` than image width, because by default wrapfigure adds space around itself. And please don't insert your code as an image but as actual code (insert it, mark it and then hit the code buttom in the editor). And a minimal working example starts at `\documentclass` and ends at `\end{document}`.

Comment: Also your image is a table and therefore you should use `wraptable` instead of `wrapfigure`.

Comment: There may be a conflict with another package.